# Is there a 3d vector class for android?

Tags: android, vector, opengl-es

As far as OpenGL is concerned on android, it looks like the matrix operations like glTranslate, glScale and glRotate only take their parameters as discrete entries.  Is there 3d vector in android that takes care of the common arithmetic operations?  Is there a way to array of floats or some sort of vector object to these functions instead of having to write out the individually every time?

Answer (score 4):

This one has been around awhile:

http://www.objectclub.jp/download/vecmath_e